# Android Studio 2.2 Error gradle android

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am having a problem when I made apk.
I am new to android studio.
This error code me.

Error:(22, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Myproject'.

> Could not find method android() for arguments 
>   [build_85cplmqmhqssq9jxuvbgjq6cp$_run_closure3@6178933f] on root
>   project 'Myproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

and shows here my **build.gradle**:

Project Level:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level :

```
android {        <=========================== **This Source Error**
        compileSdkVersion 14
        buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'
        dexOptions {
            incremental true
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
    dependencies {
    }
```

Comment: Try moving the declaration starting from `android {...}` including `dependency {  }` into `build.gradle (Module:app)` not in `build.gradle(Project: Myproject)`